# Paste multi-line text into Powerpoint

Tags: ms-office, copy-paste

I'm trying to make a Powerpoint presentation containing source code examples (something along the lines of:

```
if (date == 13) {
    cout << "Good luck!";
}
```

Without fail, when I copy and paste this from my text editor (that has this text as plain text and not as any sort of rich text) all of the text ends up as a single line in my presentation.

Is there a way to paste plain text from the system clipboard into Powerpoint while preserving line breaks in the text?

Comment: I didn't purchase a Mac to continue to have to use Microsoft products, so I don't have PowerPoint installed, however it pastes fine in Keynote and also LibreOffice Presentation. I'm surprised it doesn't paste correctly in PowerPoint.